# WinJS: How can I access page functions and variables from HTML?

Tags: windows-8, winjs

I'm defining page with some vars and methods. Then I wanna use it in html markup (for example `data-win-bind="textContent: myPage.variable`). How can I access page variables in html markup?

Comment: via javascript. html is not a programming language.;

Comment: sorry. I have marked it as "Windows-8", "WinJS" but forgot to mension about it in question - my question is about WinJS lib

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the JavaScript code behind your page, say default.js, you'd include your ViewModel for the data binding, something like:

```
(function(){
   WinJS.Namespace.define("MyModel.myPage", {
      variable : null
   };
   MyModel.myPage.variable = 'foo';
})();
```

Then in when the page is activated (in default.js), you'll need to initialize the bindings with a call like

```
WinJS.Binding.processAll(document.body, MyModel);
```

There's quite a bit more functionality available though, so this is just a simplistic one-way binding case that should get you started.  For more info, check out the [Quickstart: binding data and styles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh700358.aspx).

Answer (score -1):

You have to use javascript here's the skeleton:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
//Code goes here
</script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
<html>
```

Comment: i didn't have downvoted, but did you really read the OP's question completely ?